# Chat-Heads-Like Popup window

Tags: android, popup

I searched the web for how to make a popup window like Facebook's Chat Heads.

I found the following code: http://www.piwai.info/chatheads-basics/

```
public class ChatHeadService extends Service {

  private WindowManager windowManager;
  private ImageView chatHead;

  @Override public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // Not used
    return null;
  }

  @Override public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

    chatHead = new ImageView(this);
    chatHead.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
    params.x = 0;
    params.y = 100;

    windowManager.addView(chatHead, params);
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (chatHead != null) windowManager.removeView(chatHead);
  }
}
```

In my Main Activity:

```
startService(new Intent(context, ChatHeadService.class));
```

And I use the permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```

But I don't get the popup notification. Not even his icon.
Can you help me an say what's wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have added your service to AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <service android:name=".ChatHeadService" ></service>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Copy/Paste this in your project or you can create a new project and copy/paste this into it(with the required imports).

MainActivity.class

```
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is   present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
         }

       @Override
       public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

       // Method to start the service
       public void startService(View view) {
          startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), ChatHeadService.class));
       }

       // Method to stop the service
       public void stopService(View view) {
          stopService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), ChatHeadService.class));
       }
    }
```

ChatHeadService.class

```
    public class CloseChatHead extends Service {

        private WindowManager windowManager;
        private ImageView close;

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // Not used
        return null;
        }

        WindowManager.LayoutParams mParams;


        public WindowManager.LayoutParams getParams(){
        return mParams;
        }


        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);


        close = new ImageView(this);
        close.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle_close);

        final WindowManager.LayoutParams params1 = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        params1.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
        //params1.x = 0;
        //params1.y = 100;

        mParams=params1;

        close.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            private int initialX;
            private int initialY;
            private float initialTouchX;
            private float initialTouchY;

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ACTION_DOWN 2",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    initialX = params1.x;
                    initialY = params1.y;
                    initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                    initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    params1.x = initialX
                            + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                    params1.y = initialY
                            + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                    windowManager.updateViewLayout(close, params1);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        windowManager.addView(close, params1);

        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (close != null)
            windowManager.removeView(close);
        }
    }
```

activity_main.xml

```
   <RelativeLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.chathead.MainActivity" >

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnStartService"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="startService"
            android:text="start_service" />

            <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnStopService"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="stopService"
            android:text="stop_service" />
        </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.chathead"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".ChatHeadService" />
         <service android:name=".CloseChatHead" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Reference for the same: http://www.piwai.info/chatheads-basics/